# Change VIIRS Boat Detection (VBD) Data

Tags: arcmap, geotiff-tiff, csv

[image]I have download VBD data from this link : https://eogdata.mines.edu/products/vbd/ It has 4 format file like in the picture. But I want to change the format to .csv to sort the data easily.

[image]

Comment: Looks like rasters.  How should the csv look like? One row with three columns: x, y and raster value?

Comment: yeah, i want to get the coorndinate, timestamp, and the quality flag, 3 column i think @BERA